# Why the height of dendrogram based on correlation matrix is higher than 1?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchy, dendrogram, pearson-correlation

I am new to python. While I am removing multicollinear featrues by calculating the correlation matrix between different features in a same way as https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance_multicollinear.html#permutation-importance-with-multicollinear-or-correlated-features with a more specific code is presented as below:

```
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
from collections import defaultdict
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, fcluster,distance

corr = spearmanr(data_all[feature_name]).correlation

# Ensure the correlation matrix is symmetric
corr = (corr + corr.T) / 2
np.fill_diagonal(corr, 1)

# We convert the correlation matrix to a distance matrix before performing
# hierarchical clustering using Ward's linkage.
distance_matrix = 1 - np.abs(corr)
y = distance.squareform(distance_matrix)
dist_linkage = linkage(y,method='ward')
```

I got a result as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL18L.png)

The height of the dendrogram is higher than 1, the maximum value of y. Is this result reasonable? If so, how is the height defined in hierarchy.linkage?

I did double check to make sure that the maximum value of y is smaller than 1. As I understand that whether methods for linkage, that is minimum, maximum, average, or square error ("ward"), the distance based on input y shall also be smaller than 1. Besides, the results of the manual of sklearn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance_multicollinear.html#permutation-importance-with-multicollinear-or-correlated-features also gives a result higher than 1. I am pretty confused on the results.

Comment: please insert link and image correctly